# Image Srink After Splash Screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, splash-screen

We are creating a replica for splash screen with some animation. So we are using same image on full sreen on LaunchScreen.storyboard with top, bottom, leading and trailing.

[image]

Now I use same constraint on CustomSplashScreen.storyboard.

when I luanch app Splash screen is perfect but as soon as we land on CustomSplashScreen, image get srink. We have same image content mode as `.aspectFit.`

Please guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: If the image is "shrinking" (or otherwise not aligning), you almost certainly have a mis-match in your constraints. Double-check that on both your SplashScreen and your CustomSplashScreen **ALL** of the image view's constraints are either to the Safe-Area or to the Superview.... you *probably* have one set to Safe-Area and one set to Superview.